# Understanding when to use git commit -m and git commit -am

Tags: git

My main question here is whether iti makes sense to just always do `git commit -am` instead of `git add` . followed by `git commit -m`?

I understand that -am indicates that it will add all changes from modified TRACKED files.  So in a situation where I did not add any new files, it would make sense to just run git commit -am instead of git add, but would it be considered best practice to just do:

`git add` .

```
git commit -am "message"
```

anyway?

or even instead:

```
git add -A

git commit -am "message"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> would it be considered best practice to just do:
>
> git add .
>
> git commit -am "message"
>
> anyway?

No, there is no such "best practice". As long as you do not want to include any untracked files, `git add` + `git commit -m` and `git commit -am` will do exactly the same.

There are two situations where you need to to use `git add`:

- if you want to include untracked files, and
- if you do not want to commit everything that changed

The second point in particular is the reason many people recommend against always using `commit -a`:
After working on code for a while, you often have several different types of changes in your working copy (the bugfix you were working on, some unrelated renaming, some temporary changes for debugging...). `commit -a` risks putting too much into one commit - in these cases selective use of `git add` is better.

But if you are certain you want to commit everything you changed, go ahead and use `git commit -a`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  I sometimes need that "aha!" moment.  I was working on a very small project, so when I was making a commit, it was typically a commit of every single thing that had changed from the last commit, in which case I was getting tired of git add -A git commit -m, but want to get into better habits.

Answer (score 3):

I have committed enough code accidentally by doing `-am` that I generally avoid it these days. `git add -u` will stage the same changes as the `git commit -a` and then you can do a `git diff --cached` to make sure you want to commit them. Some of my colleagues even go so far as to always do `git add -p` so they have to look at every diff before it's even staged.

If I know the changes I've made are small then i'll still use `git commit -am` for convenience, but it may be worth getting out of that being the default habit.

Answer (score 3):

If you keep your `.gitignore` current, then `git commit -am` is a perfectly adequate way to do things.  It is a shortcut for `git add -uA <nopattern> ; git commit -m "message"`.

This is git, best practice is subjective.  I prefer to add files manually so that I get a chance to review changes as I go, but you might not need that.